# Why isn't a ring a delta-ring?

Tags: measure-theory

A ring is closed under intersection. And delta-ring is closed under countable intersection. According to my understanding, if a family of sets is closed under intersection, than it should also be closed under countable intersection.
Let's say $R$ is a ring. To $R$ be a delta-ring, $A_n\cap A_{n+1}\cap A_{n+2}\cap ...$ should also be in $R$. And, as a ring is closed under intersection, $A_n\cap A_{n+1}$ is in $R$, then $A_n\cap A_{n+1}\cap A_{n+2}$ is in R, and so on. So, any ring is a delta-ring.
What am I missing? I guess I don't properly understand what countable intersection is. Thank you for reading!

Comment: "if a family of sets is closed under intersection, than it should also be closed under countable intersection" This is not true. Take the family of open sets on $\mathbb{R}$, for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure under intersection (i.e. of two elements) implies closure under *finite* intersection by induction. It does not imply closure under countable (i.e. a type of infinite) intersection.

Take a simple example from topology. The intervals $$\Big( -\frac{1}{i}, \frac{1}{i} \Big)$$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots$ are open, and it's known in topology (and reasonably intuitive, I think) that the intersection of finitely many, i.e. $$\bigcap_{i = 1}^n \Big( -\frac{1}{i}, \frac{1}{i} \Big)$$ is still an open set. But I think it's also quite clear that the *countable* intersection $$\bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty} \Big( -\frac{1}{i}, \frac{1}{i} \Big)$$ is *not* an open set.

Note: I should mention that "countable" is sometimes used to mean "countably infinite", but in certain places it's used as an umbrella term for "finite or denumerable", where denumerable means "can be put into bijection with the natural numbers".

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer with an example. But I'm very poor at math, and it's quite hard to understand from your example. If you are patient enough, please answer this follow up question.
Here is what I understood. So, open interval means a set of points in the interval except the end points. And you are saying that the intervals you defined for every i in natrual number is a ring, but not a delta-ring.

Comment: But, from my understanding, it is still a delta-ring. The intersection from i to n is equal to (-1/n, 1/n). So, it should be in the ring you defined. And the countable intersection is (-1/∞, 1/∞) which is an empty set. (or is it {0}?) Whatever the case, (-1/∞, 1/∞) is in the ring, so it is a delta-ring. What goes wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @calee $0\in(-\frac1i,\frac1i)$ for *every* positive integer $i$ so is an element of the intersection of these open intervals. Further $0$ is unique in having this property. Then we conclude that the intersection is exactly the set $\{0\}$. This however is not an open set. So the collection of open sets is not closed under countable intersection. This in spite of the fact that it is closed under (finite) intersection.

Comment: @calee The point is that something changed when we passed from a finite intersection to an infinite intersection. For any finite intersection as I described, the result is still an object of the same type: an open interval. But for the infinite intersection we got something fundamentally different: a single number, zero. We didn't get another open interval! Therefore the open intervals are not "closed" under infinite intersection. I.e., infinite intersection produced a thing that is not another open interval.

Comment: I still don't get it. Maybe because of the lack of knowledge about infinity. But I see what you guys trying to explain. (the countable intersection of open sets can be closed set.) So, let me just stop doing commenting and I think I need to study about infinity or other things. Thank you.

Comment: I listened to a lecture about limit from Khan academy, and now I think I understand the difference. So, however you choose a big number from natural numbers, you never get a closed interval. But if you take limit, in other words if you choose a larger number, every time you choose, it will be closer to {0}. It can never be {0}, but it is just enough that it approaches to {0}. This is what I could't see, before I have proper understanding about limit.